# php - uploading custom images on product page via AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, file-upload, e-commerce

I am writing a small e-commerce website and I need to be able to allow users to upload their own custom images (limited to JPG or PNG) before they add to basket so that the images can be included with the order.

My current idea is to upload the files via AJAX and insert the filenames into the database so I can then link the images to a product and a specific order in the database. However, I have read that you cannot easily do this with AJAX as it is not yet supported?

Should I literally use a normal file upload form and process the $_FILES and $_POST requests after the form is submitted. This is already being done when items are being added to the basket so would be possible, although this could take a while to process the uploads.

Am I missing an obvious method that will solve the problem?

Comment: I'm looking at using Iframes to upload the image files and get a json returned to process the file data.

Answer (score 0):

You need to post the form to a hidden iframe, output a json response to the iframe and then parse the response via javascript.